# How to disable SSL verification in Expo CLI?

Tags: react-native, ssl, expo, ssl-certificate

I have been trying to disable SSL verification for the expo app for past 2 weeks. Is there any method to disabling SSL verification

No method found on solving this issue, rn-fetch-blob too is not working and there is no method in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In the app.json file add following code

```
"expo": {
    "ios": {
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSAppTransportSecurity" : {
          "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" : true
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This helped me to reach http endpoints

Comment: I think that the question was more about the verification of the certificate chains provided by the endpoint than reaching endpoints without TLS.